# Youtube minimizes full screen on, 2 monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, youtube, fullscreen, flash-player

I am using windows 7. I am using two screens on my computer. When I watch YouTube one of them in full screen and the click on the other screen somewhere YouTube goes out of full screen. What is the cause of this problem? How do I fix it.
I am using google chrome.
My specs are
i7 2600k @ 3.4ghz
Nvidia 580
12gb RAM

Comment: I don't think there is a fix for it, something embedded in flash, cause it happens in firefox as well.

Answer (score 4):

That is the behavior of Youtube's website, and unfortunately there are no workarounds other than the following:

Modify the URL of the video you are viewing from this:

[`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbOEknbi4gQ`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbOEknbi4gQ)

To this:

[`https://www.youtube.com/v/mbOEknbi4gQ`](https://www.youtube.com/v/mbOEknbi4gQ)

The video will then play natively full screen, and you can use Chrome's full-screen mode without the "bug" of shrinking when you click elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can only attest to this behaviour in Firefox, but this is what I do: create a new window (or tab, and drag it out to become a new window) and put your Youtube vid on there. Hit fullscreen, and whenever you click on the other monitor it shouldn't leave the fullscreen, although in my case it brings up the Windows taskbar. You'll have to live with that.